# MySQL ST_Intersection doesn't permit geographic SRS arguments

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I've installed mysql-community-server 8.0.27, expecting `ST_Intersection` to permit arguments in either a Cartesian or a geographic SRS as the doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-intersection says, but got an error:

```
mysql> set @b1 = ST_Buffer(ST_SRID(POINT(0, 0), 4326), 1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @b2 = ST_Buffer(ST_SRID(POINT(0, 0), 4326), 2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ST_Intersection(@b1, @b2);
ERROR 3618 (22S00): st_intersection(POLYGON, POLYGON) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems.
```

While it's fine to use Cartesian arguments by changing the SRID from 4326 to 0.

Am I missing something, or is the doc inaccurate?

Answer (score 1):

There's a work around for the *bug?*, since [`ST_DIFFERENCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-difference) works fine.

e.g. To calculate the area of the intersection, the expected call:

```
select ST_Area(ST_Intersection(@b1, @b2));
```

can be achieved by:

```
select ST_Area(@b1) - ST_Area(ST_Difference(@b1, @b2));
```